# Clarification on order of $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(1+i)$ and more

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $n=|\mathbb{Z}[i]/(1+i)|$

Need to show it is isomorphic to a field of order n once I find n.

I know $(1+i)$ is maximal in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Kind of confused on quotients like this. Saw the other solution: 2/(1+i)=(1-i) etc. No idea what it means.

I know I might need to use isomorphic theorem. Please no modular arithmetic.

Comment: Do you know the rule $|\Bbb{Z}[i]/(ai+b)|= a^2+b^2$? This is very useful, and it gives you directly that $n=2$.

Comment: Nope have to prove anything I use

Comment: It is easiest to use modular arithmetic, which is essential when working with quotients. Does it make sense that $1 + i \equiv 0 \mod (1 + i)$? That implies that $1 \equiv - i \mod (1 + i)$ and makes reducing elements of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ mod $(1 + i)$ a lot simpler as well as your problem as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

Since you know that $2=(1-i)(1+i)$, you have that in the quotient
$$ \overline{a+bi} = \overline{a} + \overline{i}\overline{b} = \overline{a}-\overline{b} = \overline{a-b} = (a-b) \mod{2}$$
So that the elements of $\Bbb{Z}[i]/(i+1)$ are $\overline{0},\overline{1}$.

Comment: Nope don't understand the lines above the a+bi. I did say no modular arithmetic for that reason

Comment: How can you work with a quotient without modular arithmetic? It's like asking about calculus without limits.

Comment: Explain the lines above the a+bi. Equivalence classes? Is there another notation

Comment: Yes: overline denotes the equivalence class. Firstly, you can show that all classes can be represented by an integer, just because $\overline{i} = \overline{1}$. Secondly, every integer is equivalent to its remainder of the division by $2$, just because in this quotient $\overline{2}= \overline{0}$.

Comment: Ok how do I show it is isomorphic to F_2

Comment: Well, there are two elements, namely $\overline{0}, \overline{1}$. Can you see what would be an isomorphism to $\Bbb{F}_2$?

Comment: So they both have 2 elements so are isomorphic?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\mathbb Z[i]\cong \mathbb Z[x]/(x^2+1)$. The image of the ideal $(1+i)$ under this isomorphism is $(1+x,x^2+1)/(x^2+1)$, hence $$\mathbb Z[i]/(1+i) \cong [\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2+1)]/[(1+x,x^2+1)/(x^2+1)] \cong \mathbb Z[x]/(1+x,x^2+1)$$

Comment: Why is the first isomorphism true and the rest? Can this be done using kernels and images?